# How define query string for post permalink in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, iis, permalinks

I have a WordPress site setup on IIS.

I want set a custom permalink for posts like this:

```
example.com/post.aspx?post=%post_name%
```

But instead I get *page not found* error.

Comment: go to permalink section. where u get url change

Comment: Change default .htaccess to :                                            # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress                                                                    After that change permalink structure.

Comment: I use IIS and con not finde .htaccess file :(

Comment: `.htaccess` is generated by WordPress when saving your permalink structure. If it's not, then WP (IIS) doesn't have permission to create it. If it exists and still isn't working, then you need to enable the IIS URL Re-Write module.